# What's the jquery syntax for click function of submit button

Tags: jquery, click, submit

my form has a submit button that's been defined this way:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-reg" value="Register" class="submit button">
```

What is the syntax to call the button's jquery click() function?
I've tried:

```
$('#submit-reg').click(function()...
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Give `id=submit-red` to `<input ...>`

Comment: What Harry Joy said. # is the prefix for an id selector. Your example doesn't work because the form doesn't have an id="submit-reg".

Comment: @Harry and @Paruse, thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
  alert('Button clicked');
});

or   

 use id="submit-reg"  # is use for id
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Uuqt8/1/

Comment: thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
     //click event
 });
```

You don't need to change your html if you use above function.

Comment: thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.

Comment: @Ash, where is alex's answer?

Comment: I guesse he removed it for some reason.

Comment: @alex, sorry if I did something wrong. I certainly didn't mean to.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <form action=""> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":submit").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit"  name="submit-reg" 
      value="Register" class="submit button">
```

you can select by name

`$('input[name=submit-reg]').click(...`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGTyN/)

[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is a useful link

Comment: I don't wish to change the button's definition since it's been defined in a WordPress plugin. I just want to write the correct click function code.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$('#submit-reg').click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
//rest of your code will go here
});
```

Comment: thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it only matches the one element (since .submit could match any number of elements), you could use:

```
$("input[name='submit-reg']")
```

Comment: thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[@name='submit-reg']").click(
function()
{
   //Code
});
```

Try this jquery code

And, if you want to stop other click events on the same input button then try this

```
$("input[@name='submit-reg']").click(
function(event)
{
   event.stopPropagation();
   //Code
});
```

Comment: thanks but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Please see my comment to alex's answer.